# x86 type Publish code is not working for ACE.OLEDB.4.0 provider in windows server 2008 x64

Tags: .net

x86 type Publish code is not working for ACE.OLEDB.4.0 provider in windows server 2008 x64 :

Error : ACE.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered in your local system.
i was developed application on vs 2005 for read xls file. there is working fine from vs2005 debuging mode. but when i publish it and make virtual directory from iis then it generate above error.
when i run from xp machine then it working fine,but windows server 2008 is n

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the server you are deploying to is missing a dependency.  In particular, ACE.OLEDB version 4.0 does not seem to be installed or its library was not published to the target machine.  If you believe that the dependency has been provided, make sure that it is compatible with x64 machines.